# Rest API testing using Grails REST Client Builder

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I am writing test cases to verify the response from REST call. I am doing the following:

```
RestResponse response = rest.get("http://localhost:8080/dynamic-content-services/api/"
```

But I want to use the in-memory database. I know localhost will not work but what will be the URL in that case?

This is my test environment

```
test {
    dataSource {
        driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
        username = "sa"
        password = ""
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
    }
}
```

Comment: need more details. You need to provide an in memory database connection string in your grails config for tests.

Comment: what has the DB to do with your call to localhost?  could you please provide more information, about what you are after?

Comment: If I make a request to the localhost it fetches data from my local database by what I want to do is that it should fetch data from the in memory database

Answer (score 1):

you can have a look to this post I wrote. It might help you out:

- http://aruizca.com/integrated-vs-functional-testing-how-to-test-rest-apis-in-grails-using-spock/

Look at the functional testing part. The default H2 configuration for test should work out of the box.